# Multiple checkboxes check as in Gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, checkbox

I'm trying to copy the behavior of Gmail with the checkboxes, selecting a whole range click on one and then shift-clicking another, the checkboxes in between these will change.

However, I'm having a compatibility issue between Firefox and Chrome as clicking the checkboxes works just fine, but clicking the labels somehow it's handled very differently, as Firefox will apparently not trigger the change when shift-clicking.

[You can check and test my code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Prxdn/)

Obviously there's a trouble with Firefox and the label, I've tried triggering the checkbox's `change()`, but it works backwards the behavior of the checkbox, I've tried 'resetting' the label events with `preventDefault()` and then triggering the `change()` event and the issue seems to be the same, but now Chrome has this *bug* (which I think it's somehow the correct way, first homologizing).

The easy way is detecting browsers, but every web developer guru tells us that it's better to identify the problem rather than the browser, so what would be a good fix for this? Also, it doesn't work in IE because it doesn't support `indexOf()`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the implementation of `indexOf` from the Mozilla doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) to add that functionality for browsers that don't have it.

Comment: Off-topic: besides the browser thing, I think you have some problem in the logic. After making many random clicks with shift pressed, I began noticing that the behavior of the check boxes doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Just so you know, it is generally well-accepted that the "click" event is the way to go instead of the change one. I pretty sure different browsers had issues with change.

Comment: Not a finished solution (kids need food sorry). Here is some refactoring that may be useful. http://jsfiddle.net/Prxdn/3/

Comment: @bdukes, yeah, I'll use it, but first things first
@Ilya Kogan, weird, it works just fine for me.
@Christian, ok, I'll try it, thanks.
@rcravents, hey, thanks, but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the  tag is working differently when highlighting text in Firefox. I think the reason it is failing is because when you hold down shift and click on the label, it doesn't check the box and thus doesn't fire the labeled event.

Check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/xerf/Prxdn/10/

This works both in webkit and FireFox. I changed the labels to span tags. With a bit of CSS, you can fix the padding.